# CHECK constraint with multiple conditions MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE shoesize( 
nr TINYINT NOT NULL,
shoesize VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

CHECK (shoesize = 'mini' OR 'medium' OR 'maxi'),
PRIMARY KEY (nr)
)engine=innodb;


insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('1','mini');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('2','medium');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('3','maxi');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('4','ultra');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('5','mega');

    Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'shoesize_chk_1' is violated.    0.015 sec
```

I'm trying to make a constraint, that says only shoes where a certain text is accepted. However the constraint fires when I try to enter data. It should be possible to have an OR in the check as far as I'm concerned?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a separate table for sizes with a valid key constraint.  What you've done there is essentially hard code the valid values for shoesize into the CHECK.  Create a table for all known shoe sizes, give each one a primary id, and use a foreign key constraint to refer to the size from the shoesize table .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that only the first value mini is cheked, but you need to repeat the equation to get  also the rest

```
CREATE TABLE shoesize( 
nr TINYINT NOT NULL,
shoesize VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,

CHECK (shoesize = 'mini' OR  shoesize =  'medium' OR shoesize = 'maxi'),
PRIMARY KEY (nr)
)engine=innodb;


insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('1','mini');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('2','medium');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('3','maxi');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('4','ultra');
insert into shoesize(nr,shoesize) values ('5','mega');
```

```
SELECT * FROM shoesize
```

| nr | shoesize |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | mini |
| 2 | medium |
| 3 | maxi |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pQyOoL3g)

Comment: @xtremesnus take a good look at how nbk use the fiddle site to demonstrate the solution.  You can do the same next time to demonstrate the problem, and to experiment for yourself.